# Any css or javascript techniques to display a 'slice' of a circle image?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to write a program where users upload circular images like this deliciously warm pizza:[image]

The user then specifies the start and end of the arc in degrees so that a function will be called to display the same image, with a lower opacity on the leftover portion.

```
function cutPizza (startArcDegree, endArcDegree){
//This is where I need help    
}

cutPizza(150, 225);
```

[image]

Are there any css or javascript techniques to help me achieve this (Or any or ways for that matter)?

Comment: +1 for 'deliciously warm pizza'

Comment: Can you show us what you have got so far?

Comment: I usually use [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) for this sort of thing. Here's a [vaguely related demo](http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should have a canvas that has a relative position to your pizza image. Then you can draw your circle on canvas, and configure canvas transparency

Read how to draw circles from here:

http://billmill.org/static/canvastutorial/ball.html

Answer (score 4):

You could try generating a SVG and then look into [Clipping, Masking and Compositing](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html)